# Implementing Jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Im kinda having a problem in implementing `jquery ui slider`, as my clients site is currently using a `jquery 2.0.2 version` I can't seem to bring the slider out.

I wanted to use the `slider-range` --> http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

And the `script` and `css` includes in the documentations are;

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

So, Im my code i tried,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

But its not working, here is a sample of what i did [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/39feX/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your missing the `jQuery/javascript` used to initialize the slider?

```
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/39feX/2/

Comment: @rockStar no problem, please mark this answer as accepted if it resolved your question.  Thanks